# Kentor:[KeyNotFoundException: No Idp with entity id "http://adfs.domain.com/adfs/services/trust" found.]

Tags: kentor-authservices

We have a requirement to enable SAML SSO login, we are  implementing SSO using Kentor HttpModule. 
 I'm facing an issue when the Idp calls my application. The kentor service throws The given key was not present in the dictionary. Here the idp is ADFS.

We tried using the stubidp and it works fine.

Below is my Saml configuration

```
        private static IdentityProvider CreateAuthServicesOptions()
    {
        var spOptions = GetServiceProviderOptions();


        var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("http://IQTDEV01.domain.com/adfs/services/trust/"), spOptions)
        {
            AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
            Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpPost,
            WantAuthnRequestsSigned=true,
            //LoadMetadata = true,
            SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("https://IQTDEV01.iqtrackdev.com/adfs/ls/")
        };

        idp.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(
                new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "/ADFSService.cer"));

        return idp;
    }

    private static SPOptions GetServiceProviderOptions()
    {
        var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");


        var spOptions = new SPOptions
        {
            EntityId = new EntityId("https://app.domain.com/AuthServices/"),
            ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://app.domain.com"),

            AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior=SigningBehavior.Always

        };
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "‎FDDAF5EAA6E2B232E0012C0E77955C13246D2DF4", false);


        Kentor.AuthServices.ServiceCertificate ser = new Kentor.AuthServices.ServiceCertificate();
        ser.Certificate = cers[0];
        ser.Use = Kentor.AuthServices.CertificateUse.Signing;
        spOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(ser);

        //spOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(
        //        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "/ADFSService.cer"));

        return spOptions;
    }

    protected void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

        // Strip the leading ~ from the AppRelative path.
        var appRelativePath = application.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
        appRelativePath = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appRelativePath))
            ? appRelativePath.Substring(1)
            : string.Empty;          

        if (application.Request != null)
      {


            Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration.Options op = new Options(GetServiceProviderOptions());



            op.IdentityProviders.Add(CreateAuthServicesOptions());
            Options = op;
        }

        var modulePath = Options.SPOptions.ModulePath;

        if (appRelativePath.StartsWith(modulePath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var commandName = appRelativePath.Substring(modulePath.Length);

            var command = CommandFactory.GetCommand(commandName);
            var commandResult = command.Run(
                new HttpRequestWrapper(application.Request).ToHttpRequestData(),
                Options);

            if (!commandResult.HandledResult)
            {
                commandResult.SignInOrOutSessionAuthenticationModule();
                commandResult.Apply(new HttpResponseWrapper(application.Response));
            }
        }
    }
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFWVW.png)